# SQL Select distinct values from multiple tables

Tags: sql, distinct

So here's my setup I have 2 tables Old and New with the following (simplified) schemas

```
Old
[ManName]
[ManNumber]

New
[Manager_Name]
[Manager_Number]
```

I'm looking to craft a SQL query that returns the following but in 4 columns in 1 query as opposed to 2 queries with 2 columns each

```
select distinct manname, mannumber from OLD 
select distinct Manager_Name, Manager_Number from NEW
```

So my ideal Result Set would have 4 columns:

```
ManName ManNumber Manager_Name Manager Number
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give an example of table data and desired output? Also, which RDBMS? SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried a JOIN statement:

```
select distinct * 
from old a join new b on a.ManName = b. Manager_Name and a. ManNumber = b. Manager_Number
```

Comment: Excellent Thanks! I had almost all of it in my solution, I never thought to join on both columns however.

Comment: @BobFishel This will show all managers that match between the tables, but none of those that don't. May be what you want, but not quite what you asked :)

Comment: yep I switched it to a full outer join :)

Answer (score 2):

Using pretty much any RDBMS except MySQL, you can do it with CTEs and `ROW_NUMBER()`;

```
WITH cteOld AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT ManName, ManNumber, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ManNumber) rn FROM Old
), cteNew AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT Manager_Name, Manager_Number,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Manager_Number) rn FROM New
)
SELECT ManName, ManNumber, Manager_Name, Manager_Number 
FROM cteOld
FULL OUTER JOIN cteNew
  ON cteOld.rn=cteNew.rn
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b232/5).

Another, easier, way to just get all of them is to simply use a UNION;

```
SELECT ManName, ManNumber, 0 isNew FROM Old
UNION 
SELECT Manager_Name, Manager_Number, 1 FROM New
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b232/7).